# Chrome Driver Error message

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Related to this error there are many question asked in stack overflow. I checked those question and the solution too but that didn't resolve my issue. Below is the error message along with the details

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

i have tried the solution given in internet. but still my driver is showing as 2.33 and i am not able to delete the existing chrome driver from the Webdriver folder of my project

Comment: restart the machine and then try to delete !

Comment: i was able to delete the chrome driver.

Comment: @Hargovind `chromedriver=2.33` and `chrome=66.0` is not in sync. See [ChromeDriver Release Notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt)

Comment: i have installed chrome driver version 2.37 and re-run my scripts and it worked successfully in chrome. I guess i missed we things from the previous solution. Thanks for the support.